# What are the low cost options for converting FLEX API based web mapping applications to any other platform?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, flex, arcgis-portal

As flex is reaching the end of its life, I have one project to convert Flex based web mapping application to any other possible solution with minimum development effort and secure way. I believe Dojo based ESRI javascript API (as Siverlight direction is not clear either) will suit the need here (If company's policy allows cloud and then ArcGIS Portal can be leveraged too). But there are some suggestions around Geocortex framework or any microsoft based approach. The belief is Geocortex framework can give a secure and objects based development approach. But in one of the project I worked with Geocortex and multiple web mapping application- I found the development effort was so much underestimated under similar assumptions and project was running into mess. Any suggestion/ opinion/ experience will be helpful here. There is another web mapping application based on leaflet based ESRI API with Angular JS used by the organization and some of the client need can be microscopic too. Will Dojo be able to meet the need here?

Comment: I can tell you that I moved our organization to Geocortex Essentials with amazing results. The set up is simple and the back end interface where you set up your maps is much improved as of the 4.3 release. Cost was around 20k but its a COTS product so you don't have to spend time keeping up with versions of ArcGIS JavaScript API and maintaining code in house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Esri JavaScript API has improved dramatically in the last couple years, I have enjoyed my experience with porting Flex apps to the JavaScript API. One thing that has really helped - that should not be as difficult to do as it is - is setting up a build process. Because Esri doesn't release their code, you have to use their built version. This means you have the entire framework even though you may not need everything in it. This excellent post helped me in figuring out how to get the AMD modules to setup a proper Dojo build process to get all of the esri code, my custom code, as well as other libraries (Cesium for example) built together and only build what I need:

http://gis.utah.gov/the-esri-api-for-javascriptdojo-build-system-saga-continues/
http://gis.utah.gov/grunt-esri-slurp/

I've also used custom projections (planets/asteroids) that Esri doesn't have Well-Known ID's (WKID) for, but using the Well-Known Text (WKT) strings has worked just fine.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I am trying to understand the security details of webmap published on ArcGIS portal. My company works with third party data\images for government projects. We neither want to expose data to public and nor want to charge the money per user\credit basis. So we want to keep the webmap secure but still independent of any use basis charges or authentication.

Answer (score 0):

"Low cost" and "minimum development effort" are relative terms. I recently converted a Silverlight application to use the ESRI JavaScript API. I developed the app in-house so it didn't cost anything other than my salary.

However, if you take this approach you will have to take into account your current knowledge of [Dojo and AMD](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_dojo_amd.html) as this could impact how much effort you have to put into development. ESRI has a lot of example code and widgets to help you get up and running quickly though.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the middle of converting a Flex based ArcGIS system into Javascript using the javascript API. The biggest mistake I made so far was using old Legacy code as compared to the more modern AMD. This caused me to rewrite and organize some javascript which was a waste of my time. I would say that doing it in-house is pretty low cost compared to outsourcing the work. However, you are doing the development effort yourself. That being said, I would definitely suggest converting to a Javascript based system. This will allow for mobile device compatibility and is quite easy for creating a responsive web-based system.

Comment: I played with web app builder - it looks good so far. Have you had any trouble dealing with custom projections? e.g. we deal with ['transit projection'](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8012/)

Comment: I use a custom projection on the app I am building. For the most part it works well. The only issues I have had have typically been from using the data incorrectly. If your projections are set up properly then I don't see there being much of an issue.